# How does a thread return a value through yield in a bokeh callback?

Tags: python, tornado, bokeh

The [bokeh server documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) gives an example of “updating from unlocked callbacks.”  The “unlocked callback” in question is the following:

```
@gen.coroutine
@without_document_lock()
def unlocked_task():
    global i
    i += 1
    res = yield executor.submit(blocking_task, i)
    doc.add_next_tick_callback(partial(locked_update, i=res))
```

This callback is driven by a periodic callback in the bokeh server.

I don’t understand how the variable `res` is updated in this code.  My understanding was that in the `yield` statement, the `blocking_task`code is submitted to the executor threadpool and then the task suspends pending its completion.  The result of the submit is returned to the calling function (presumably the event loop driving the server).  When next called, res gets the value passed to the coroutine from the caller.

Since I don’t believe the server passes any values to functions in periodic callbacks, and executor.submit returns a Future that goes back to the calling routine,  how does `res` get updated?